# Why when I create new object with Object.assign from two object instances it still references old object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm creating little tool which contains references to nodes in DOM. And sometimes I need to recreate the reference object and assign it to new instance. While creating this I found little weird behavior:

```
let renderd = this.renderedElements;
  if (Elements[this.alias] && Elements[this.alias].renderedElements[name]) {
    renderd = Object.assign(this.renderedElements,Elements[this.alias].renderedElements);
  }
```

Here I'm just checking it global object **Elements** of this duplicate exists and if contain already object with this name. And I thought it only will assign to **render** variable references to this object so I can later only iterate over one variable but it duplicates already existing renderedElements into this.renderedElements. Why?

Comment: `Object.assign` modifies the object in place. If you want to clone it, use `Object.assign({}, this.renderedElements, Elements[this.alias].renderedElements)`

Comment: Note that this is explicitly stated in the very first sentence of the [doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: yea I found it later just wanted to add as as answer but miss clicked and added as question.

Comment: @Chris G when I opened docs they were in my native language (polish) and the content wasn't so clear to me. The thought they might be vague didn't even passed my mind so I didn't checked English version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Object.assign not only return merged two objects but actually merges then into firstly passed object. So **this.renderedElements** from now on will contain **Elements[this.alias].renderedElements**. Here is script which works:

```
let renderd = Object.assign({},this.renderedElements);
  if (Elements[this.alias] && Elements[this.alias].renderedElements[name]) {
    Object.assign(renderd,Elements[this.alias].renderedElements);
  }
```

I'm cloning object **this.renderedElements** with Object.assign based on [mozzila docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object/assign) to **rendered** and later merge it with **Elements[this.alias].renderedElements**.

I had some trouble finding what and why so I hope it will help someone in future and maybe someone will expand this answer.